# Rails-money gem submit dollar value to external service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

I'm using the money-rails gem in my rails 4 app to save money values for several models. One thing that I'm noticing is the value stored in the database is the dollar value * 100 (cents value). I am pushing this field (amount) to an external service and it requires the format to be 00.00 (dollars.cents).

The push to the external service looks like the following:

```
# External service push
Restforce.new.create!('Loan__c', object.amount)

# Not clean solution
Restforce.new.create!('Loan__c', object.amount * 100)
```

Is the best way for me to solve this to multiply object.amount * 100 before I push to the external service? Is there a helper method I can use in the model to ensure I push the data in the correct format?

Comment: So do you just want the humanized_money of object.amount?

Comment: Yes. But in the model. In the docs I see they're using humanized_money @field_name. I don't think I'll be able to use an instance variable in my model. Can I use humanized_money field_name, without the instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Restforce.new.create!('Loan__c', ('%.2f' % amount))
```